# What's wrong with my LRU? Did I use std::deque mistakenly?

Tags: c++, list, deque

I'm quite frustrated about this, now I'm still have absolutely no clues why am I getting wrong.
So I'm doing LRU implementation as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class LRUCache {
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity) : cap(capacity) {
        cache.clear();
        pos_map.clear();
    }
    void check_recent() {
        cout << "recent: ";
        for (auto it : cache)
            cout << it << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    int get(int key) {
        cout << "get: " << key << " ; ";
        auto it = pos_map.find(key);
        if (it != pos_map.end()) {
            cache.erase(it->second.second);
            cache.push_front(key);
            pos_map[key].second = cache.begin();
            check_recent();
            return pos_map[key].first;
        } 
        check_recent();
        return -1;
    }
    
    void put(int key, int value) {
        cout << "put: " << key << ", " << value << " ; ";
        auto it = pos_map.find(key);
        if (it != pos_map.end()) {
            pos_map[key].first = value;
            cache.erase(it->second.second);
            cache.push_front(key);
            pos_map[key].second = cache.begin();
        } else {
            cache.push_front(key);
            if (cache.size() > cap) {
                int remove = cache.back();
                cache.pop_back();
                pos_map.erase(remove);
            }
            pos_map[key] = make_pair(value, cache.begin());
        }
        
        check_recent();
        return ;
    }
private:
    int cap;
    deque<int> cache; // deque of keys
    unordered_map<int, pair<int, deque<int>::iterator>> pos_map;
    // <key, <value, iter>>
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    LRUCache* obj = new LRUCache(10);
    obj->put(10, 13);
    obj->put(3, 17);
    obj->put(6, 11);
    obj->put(10, 5);
    obj->put(9, 10);
    obj->get(13);
    obj->put(2, 19);
    obj->get(2);
    obj->get(3);
    obj->put(5, 25);
    obj->put(9, 22);
    obj->put(5, 5);
    obj->put(1, 13);
    obj->put(9, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I get the following output:

```
Hello World
put: 10, 13 ; recent: 10 
put: 3, 17 ; recent: 3 10 
put: 6, 11 ; recent: 6 3 10 
put: 10, 5 ; recent: 10 6 3 
put: 9, 10 ; recent: 9 10 6 3 
get: 13 ; recent: 9 10 6 3 
put: 2, 19 ; recent: 2 9 10 6 3 
get: 2 ; recent: 2 9 10 6 3 
get: 3 ; recent: 3 2 9 10 6 
put: 5, 25 ; recent: 5 3 2 9 10 6 
put: 9, 22 ; recent: 9 5 3 2 10 6 
put: 5, 5 ; recent: 5 9 3 2 10 6 
put: 1, 13 ; recent: 1 5 9 3 2 10 6 
put: 9, 12 ; recent: 9 1 "9" 3 2 10 6
```

This fault "9" costs me an hour to figure out why yet in vain. But the thing is, if I change all of the std::deque in my codes to std::list, the outcome is same as my expectation:

```
put: 9, 12 ; recent: 9 1 "5" 3 2 10 6
```

So what the heck is going on with std::deque::erase? Did I do something wrong?
Can anybody guide my or gimme some clues plz?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you haven't already, step through the function with a debugger and see if you can spot unexpected behaviour. You may be able to see the problem before someone can write up  an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what the heck is going on with std::deque::erase? Did I do something wrong?

You have two data structures, one of which maps to iterators of the other:

```
    deque<int> cache; // deque of keys
    unordered_map<int, pair<int, deque<int>::iterator>> pos_map;
```

If the iterators are to a dequeue, then [the invalidation rules of `erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) state

> All iterators and references are invalidated, unless the erased elements are at the end or the beginning of the container, in which case only the iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated.

However, [for `list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) we have

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Comment: Hi @Amy Tavory, so u mean even if I stored the correct deque::iterator in the beginning, once I erase some of the element in the middle, this behavior would invalidate all the previous iterators I stored before?